# Exception while evaluating simple XPath expression

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

Hi I have a problem with an XPath expression while trying to write a test.
I have a following fragment of code.

```
final String resultCode = xPath.compile(
        "//*:Envelope/*:Body/ResultCode/text()")
        .evaluate(responseEntity.getBody());
```

The responseEntity is returned by my mock. It consists of HttpStatus and proper response body in xml format. While executing the test I get this exception

> Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: Cannot locate an object model implementation for nodes of class java.lang.String
>       at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:321)
>       at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:396)
>   ...

I am using saxon for this task, but to be honest I am not very familiar with it. Any suggestions what to check are welcome

Comment: You can try `"//*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/ResultCode/text()"`

Comment: Actually the expression as written is fine in XPath 2.0

Comment: So how can i tell it to use XPath 2.0? When the first kind(2.0 as i understand) was applied an empty result was returned, whereas the second expression finds a proper one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out. Unfortunately such things happen when you have to fix somebody's code in a field you have no knowledge at all.

The issue was that a String was passed to the `evaluate` method while it expect one of `NodeInfo`, `DOM`, `Document` etc.

Also thanks to @paul trmbrth for fixing the xpath expression which was malformed too.

I changed the code to something like this:

```
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseEntity.getBody()));
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document = db.parse(source);

final String resultCode = xPath.compile(
        "//*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ResultCode']/text()")
        .evaluate(document);
```

Comment: The XPath expression as written is fine in XPath 2. The problem was passing a string for the document to be searched. Note: with Saxon, using Saxon's tree model is going to give you much faster searching than using the DOM. The simplest way to achieve that is to use Saxon's s9api interface rather than the JAXP interface: this also has the advantage of playing much better with the extended type system of XPath 2.0.